# Yup validation convert empty string to default value

Tags: node.js, yup

In my Yup schema I was my String field `name` to allow you to pass in any string, an empty string, or nothing at all. If you pass in a string, it passes. If you pass in an empty string or nothing, I want to convert to a default value.

This is the schema that I thought would cover it:

```
const mySchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string('Name must be a string').max(100, 'Name has a max of 100 characters').default('John Doe')
});
```

However, if I pass in an empty string `''`, it does not trigger the default conversion and it just passed through as an empty string. I've tried adding `required()` but that just makes the line fail if I pass an empty string. I've tried `nullable()` and `trim()` but nothing seems to work.

How can I make the default value replace empty strings?

Comment: I think you will need to handle that case in a transform as an empty string (`''`) is a string and would not trigger the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up adding a simple method to transform empty string to undefined which will get picked up in the default:

```
// Add method
yup.addMethod(yup.string, 'stripEmptyString', function () {
  return this.transform((value) => (value === '' ? undefined : value));
});

// Usage
const mySchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string('Name must be a string').stripEmptyString().default('John Doe')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
const voidIfEmptyString = (value) => (value === '' ? undefined : value)

const mySchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string('Name must be a string')
    .transform(voidIfEmptyString)
    .max(100, 'Name has a max of 100 characters')
    .default('John Doe')
});
```